# Having trouble with css calc() with angular 5 parsing

Tags: angularjs

I need to add a margin to an element with some calculations as below:

```
[ngStyle]="{'margin-left': calc(sustainScrore && sustainScrore.scoring && sustainScrore.scoring.score ? sustainScrore.scoring.score + '%' : '0%')}"
```

This seems to throw an error :

> ERROR TypeError: _co.calc is not a function Looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
[ngStyle]="{ 'margin-left': 'calc(' + (sustainScrore?.scoring?.score || '0') + '%)' }"
```

This should do the trick.

Your issue was not considering `calc` as a string : Angular was looking for a funtion to call, while you wanted to create a CSS property. I also reduced your code with the safe navigation operator, leaving you with cleaner code.

if you want to reduce it further, use the `style.XXX` notation :

```
[style.margin-left]="'calc(' + (sustainScrore?.scoring?.score || '0') + '%)'"
```

Comment: No problem, if you think it derserves it, consider marking my answer as the solution in order to help people having the same issue resolve it !